# Inline-block div starts a new line

Tags: html, css

EDIT: If the text is short enough where the text is forced to wrap, then it behaves as I expect.  The problem is when the text is too long. Edited below to reflect this.  Please see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ew1f2asv/1/

I have the following structure

```
<div class="display_inlineblock"><img src="image.png"></div>
<div class="display_inlineblock">Hello, this is a really long sentence that causes a line break</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.display_inlineblock{
  display:inline-block; //inline or inline-block, doesn't matter
}
```

My expectation would be for the structure to look something like:

```
 -----------  ----------------
| image.png | |  Hello, this  |
 -----------  |  is a really  |
              |  long sentence|
              |  that causes  |
              |  a line break |
              -----------------
```

where the right div would grow vertically as it fills up with more text but stay on the same line as the left.

However what is happening is

```
 ----------- 
| image.png |
 -----------
----------------
|  Hello, this  |  
|  is a really  |                
|  long sentence|
|  that causes  |
|  a line break |
-----------------
```

Anyone know why?  And is there a way to achieve the first result?

Thanks!

Comment: You have your class names incorrect! Change `display_inlineblock` to `display_inline`.

Comment: Can you post a FIDDLE

Comment: Fiddle here! https://jsfiddle.net/ew1f2asv/1/

Comment: you are using div and its getting 100% width . So you can use width attribute it can fix your problem

Comment: if you change to `display:inline` it's working: https://jsfiddle.net/ew1f2asv/3/

Comment: @AkhileshSingh Makes sense!  However, actually the problem is the available width varies so I don't want to define a fixed width if possible.

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks, but that is not what I am looking for.  The line break causes the text to wrap all the way to the left again

Comment: @MoshFeu I think you linked the old fiddle, but if possible I'd like to stay away from `flexbox` because it is not supported on many older browsers

Comment: You are right. https://jsfiddle.net/ew1f2asv/7/. So what about `display:table-cell` like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ew1f2asv/8/

Comment: @MoshFeu This is perfect!  Thanks :)  I wanted to do vertical align too and not sure if the float solutions below would work for that but it works with `table-cell`.  If you make your comment an answer I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `table-cell` instead.

Like:

```css
.wrapper {
  display:table;  
}

.display_inlineblock {
  display:table-cell;  
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="display_inlineblock"><img src="image.png"></div>
  <div class="display_inlineblock">Hello, this is a really long sentence that causes a line break. Hello, this is a really long sentence that causes a line break. Hello, this is a really long sentence that causes a line break. Hello, this is a really long sentence that causes a line break. Hello, this is a really long sentence that causes a line break. </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to use `float: left` with `display: inline`.
To clear the concepts, elements with `display: block` will expand naturally to fill its parent container; elements with `display: inline` will ignore the `width` and `height` properties. However, only when `inline` elements with `float` property will automatically become a block-level element with including following of its siblings elements.

```
<div class="image-wrap"><img src="image.png"></div>
<div class="text-wrap">Hello</div>
```

With CSS:

```
.image-wrap,
.text-wrap {
  display: inline;
  float:left;
}
```

Or you may want to use `<span>` which by default is `inline`.

Comment: Yes. It only works when the text is shorts then the full width. When the text is too long, it will be treated as a whole and pushed to the next block level. For this case, you need `white-space: pre-wrap` on the text with setting `float: left` on the image. http://jsfiddle.net/m705um5d/11/

Answer (score 0):

1. try not to use the same css properties for your image tag and the div that store your text because the text div needs to be positioned differently.
2. Use a different class for the text div
3. Place your image tag and text div within a main div and apply `position:relative;`

here is a snippet how i would do this with the power of css `overflow:hidden`!

```css
#main{
  position:relative;
}
.display_inlineblock{
  float:left;
  display:block; //inline or inline-block, doesn't matter
  
}
.display_inlineblock_text{
overflow:hidden;

}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div class="display_inlineblock"><img src="image.png"></div>
<div class="display_inlineblock_text">Hello, this is a really long sentence that causes a line break. Hello, this is a really long sentence that causes a line break. Hello, this is a really long sentence that causes a line break. Hello, this is a really long sentence that causes a line break. Hello, this is a really long sentence that causes a line break. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow interesting thanks!  That is what I am looking for....how does `overflow` do that though?  I'd expect it to chop off the text rather than force it to respect the margin?